# Count matching pairs

Tags: sql, count, matching

This is a little complicated so bear with me. Below is a table named "list" with 2 columns. The table has data of each member and the films that they like. i.e member 01 likes film 02, 05, 14, 21 and 25. What I want to find out is how many similar films does each member have with another member. For example, member 01 and member 02 have one film in common (film 14). Is there any way to write this in SQL?

```
       List
------      ------
member      film
------      ------
01          02
01          05
01          14
01          21
01          25
02          03
02          09
02          14
03          01
03          05
03          17
03          21
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write a general query for this using a self-join and aggregation.  The following summarizes the results for each pair of users:

```
select l1.member, l2.member, count(*) as NumFilmsInCommon
from list l1 join
     list l2
     on l1.member < l2.member and l1.film = l2.film
group by l1.member, l2.member;
```

The `<` condition just ensures that each pair of members only appears once in the result set.